# Escaping shell cmd line nested quotes

Tags: shell, sh

I have a lot of background jobs running that are feeding their respective log files. Using the `watch` command I am monitoring the respective last line in the log as follows.

```
watch "ls -rtdc1 base_*.log | tail -20 | xargs -I % sh -c 'tail -vn1 % | cut -c1-180'"
```

That looks nice, however it has the file names from `tail -v` and following line from the log with a line break. I want to keep both on the same line. The following little awk cmd will just combine two lines and it tests out fine individually.

```
awk 'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1'
```

Ok, now combining the two is the challenge. A lot of single and double quotes to watch out for. I tried the following line at it failed.

```
watch "ls -rtdc1 base_*.log | tail -20 | xargs -I % sh -c 'tail -vn1 % | awk \'NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1\' | cut -c1-180'"
```

So my question is to find the proper escaping sequence for the cmd line.

Your feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you **really** need an answer for `sh`, not bash?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added the `sh` tag because OP originally only had `shell`, which is even less specific. The syntax and the commands in the examples show that this is some kind of unix system.

Answer (score 1):

The Right Thing is to structure your code in such a way that you *don't need to quote your code at all to make it be treated literally*.

Consider the following (noting that everywhere I have a *Function definition goes here* placeholder below, it should be replaced with the `myfn` definition given, or something equivalent thereto):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^-- needed for exported functions

myfn() {
  # aside: parsing ls is a Really Bad Idea; don't do this.
  # See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for discussion of why not.
  # See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003 for alternate practices.
  ls -rtdc1 base_*.log \
  | tail -20 \
  | while read -r line; do
      tail -v1 "$line" \
      | awk 'NR%2 {printf "%s ",$0; next; }1' \
      | cut -c1-180
    done
}
export -f myfn
watch 'bash -c myfn'
```

Alternately, without the `export -f` (and requiring bash only as the outer shell, not the inner one):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- needed for declare -f

myfn() { echo "Function definition goes here"; }

watch "$(declare -f myfn); myfn"
```

Alternately, requiring *only* /bin/sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat_myfn() {
  cat <<'EOF'
myfn() { echo "Function definition goes here"; }
EOF
}

watch "$(cat_myfn)
myfn"
```

Answer (score 1):

Charles has a good answer for your specific problem. If you are asking the general problem of quoting, then GNU Parallel can do that for you:

```
$ parallel --shellquote
NR%2{printf "%s ",$0;next;}1
[Ctrl-D]
```

so `awk NR%2\{printf\ \"%s\ \",\$0\;next\;\}1` should work. Next is to quote the command for `sh -c`:

```
$ parallel --shellquote
tail -vn1 % | awk NR%2\{printf\ \"%s\ \",\$0\;next\;\}1 | cut -c1-180
[Ctrl-D]
```

Giving:

```
tail\ -vn1\ %\ \|\ awk\ NR%2\\\{printf\\\ \\\"%s\\\ \\\",\\\$0\\\;next\\\;\\\}1\ \|\ cut\ -c1-180
```

However, since you use % in the `awk` command, you need to use another replacement string for `xargs`. Let us use {}:

```
ls -rtdc1 base_*.log | tail -20 | xargs -I {} sh -c tail\ -vn1\ {}\ \|\ awk\ NR%2\\\{printf\\\ \\\"%s\\\ \\\",\\\$0\\\;next\\\;\\\}1\ \|\ cut\ -c1-180
```

Finally to quote it for `watch`:

```
$ parallel --shellquote
ls -rtdc1 base_*.log | tail -20 | xargs -I {} sh -c tail\ -vn1\ {}\ \|\ awk\ NR%2\\\{printf\\\ \\\"%s\\\ \\\",\\\$0\\\;next\\\;\\\}1\ \|\ cut\ -c1-180
[Ctrl-D]
```

Giving:

```
ls\ -rtdc1\ base_\*.log\ \|\ tail\ -20\ \|\ xargs\ -I\ \{\}\ sh\ -c\ tail\\\ -vn1\\\ \{\}\\\ \\\|\\\ awk\\\ NR%2\\\\\\\{printf\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\"%s\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\",\\\\\\\$0\\\\\\\;next\\\\\\\;\\\\\\\}1\\\ \\\|\\\ cut\\\ -c1-180
```

This should therefore work:

```
watch ls\ -rtdc1\ base_\*.log\ \|\ tail\ -20\ \|\ xargs\ -I\ \{\}\ sh\ -c\ tail\\\ -vn1\\\ \{\}\\\ \\\|\\\ awk\\\ NR%2\\\\\\\{printf\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\"%s\\\\\\\ \\\\\\\",\\\\\\\$0\\\\\\\;next\\\\\\\;\\\\\\\}1\\\ \\\|\\\ cut\\\ -c1-180
```

Would you ever write it this way by hand? Probably not. But the whole idea is to make the computer work for you - not the other way around.

Comment: I'll need to keep this in mind -- my usual go-to (when needing `/bin/sh`-compliant quoting, making `printf %q` unsuitable) is a Python helper to use `shlex.quote()`, but Parallel is easier to use, if not quite as widely installed out-of-the-box.

Comment: `shlex.quote` seems to be limited to Bourne Shell. E.g. it does not quote = which would be needed in Zsh (`echo =ls`). In case GNU Parallel is not installed have a look at `parallel --embed`.